# Databinding Not updating

Tags: vb.net, winforms, data-binding

I have been trying to get a label to databind to a readonly property. I have a much more complex project which I am implementing this in and it isn't working. I have been unsuccessful in getting help with this so I have created a much simpler version of the project and my databinding still isn't updating.

To replicate my issue you will need a form with a textbox, label and button, and then a class.

The code for the class is as follows

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Public Class databinding
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
    Public Sub New()
        numbers = New List(Of number)
    End Sub
    Public Property numbers As List(Of number)
        Get
            Return m_number
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of number))
            m_number = value
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("hnumber"))
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_number As List(Of number)
    Public ReadOnly Property hnumber As Integer
        Get
            Dim list As IList(Of number) = (From t As number In numbers Select t Order By t.value Descending).ToList()
            If (list.Count > 0) Then
                If (IsNothing(list(0).value)) Then
                    Return "0"
                Else
                    Return list(0).value
                End If

            End If
            Return "0"
        End Get

    End Property

    Public Event PropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
End Class
Public Class number
    Public Property value As Integer
        Get
            Return t_number
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            t_number = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private t_number As Integer
End Class
```

The code for the form is as follows:

```
Public Class Form1
    Public numberlist As New databinding
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Label1.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("text", numberlist, "hnumber"))
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim newnum As New number
        newnum.value = TextBox1.Text
        numberlist.numbers.Add(newnum)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Now based on my understanding when you click the button a number from the textbox is added to this list, which happens, and the hnumber value updates, which using a breakpoint and a watch I can see also happens. From reading I need to implement inotifypropertychanged when I set the new number to get the label to re check the databind (which has been done).

However the label will stay at 0. If I run watch through Label1 I can see that under DataBindings > List > arrayList > (0) > System.Windows.Forms.Binding>DataSource>Databinding_test.databinding the details of the class (including the correct value for hnumber) is listed, so to me that shows that the Label does in fact know about the value it should be binding to.

Could someone please fill me in on what I am missing to make this all work, as it is almost causing me to pull out all of my hair.

Thanks,
mtg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to explain this to you before, and I will again.

The reason why your binding isn't updated is because you're adding the value to a list.

```
numberlist.numbers.Add(newnum)
```

However, if you "change" the list, this will trigger the propertychanged event.

```
numberlist.numbers.Add(newnum)
numberlist.numbers = numberlist.numbers '<--
```

Instead of using an `IList<T>` you should use the `ObservableCollection<T>` which allows you to track the changes made.

```
Public Class databinding
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Public Sub New()
        Me.numbers = New ObservableCollection(Of number)
    End Sub

    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Public Property numbers As ObservableCollection(Of number)
        Get
            Return m_number
        End Get
        Set(value As ObservableCollection(Of number))
            If (Not m_number Is value) Then
                Unhook(m_number)
                Hook(value)
                m_number = value
                RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("hnumber"))
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property hnumber As Integer
        Get
            If (Not numbers Is Nothing) Then
                Dim list As IList(Of number) = (From t As number In numbers Select t Order By t.value Descending).ToList()
                If (list.Count > 0) Then
                    If (IsNothing(list(0).value)) Then
                        Return 0
                    Else
                        Return list(0).value
                    End If
                End If
            End If
            Return 0
        End Get
    End Property

    Private Sub Hook(collection As ObservableCollection(Of number))
        If (Not collection Is Nothing) Then
            AddHandler collection.CollectionChanged, AddressOf Me.OnNumbersChanged
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub OnNumbersChanged(sender As Object, e As NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("hnumber"))
    End Sub

    Private Sub Unhook(collection As ObservableCollection(Of number))
        If (Not collection Is Nothing) Then
            RemoveHandler collection.CollectionChanged, AddressOf Me.OnNumbersChanged
        End If
    End Sub

    Private m_number As ObservableCollection(Of number)

End Class
```